# Precision issue with Decimal.js tan

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, bignum, decimal.js

I have been using Decimal.js to increase the precision of my function that calculates the mth positive root of `a = tan(a)` through trial and error. It works, however it returns a "Precision limit exceeded" error for `nTan(504)` (would return 4.4934... to 505 digits) and greater.

```
var Decimal = require("decimal.js");
var fs = require("fs");

function nTan (acc, m) {
    var test = [1], acc = (parseInt(acc) || 15) + 1;
    Decimal.set({precision: acc});
    var n = new Decimal(fs.readFileSync("result.txt", "utf-8") || 4.4).toString();

    while (n.length + test.length - 2 < acc) {
        var dec = (new Decimal(n + test.join("")));
        if (dec.tan().cmp(n + test.join("")) >= 0) {
            test[test.length - 1]--;
            test.push(1);
        } else test[test.length - 1]++;

        if (test[test.length - 1] == 10) { test[test.length - 1] = 9; test.push(1); }
    }

    return (new Decimal(n + test.slice(0, -1).join(""))).plus(Math.PI * (parseInt(m) || 0)).toString();
}
```

My question(s) are:

1. Why won't Decimal.js calculate past 504 digits when it advertises the capacity for up to and including 1e+9 digits?
2. Is there an alternative node or JS API that would support this program to a greater precision?

Comment: I don't understand your point/question. When calling `nTan(504)`, you are setting the precision to 504 digits. here: `Decimal.set({precision: acc})`

Comment: If I call nTan(504) Decimal.js produces a "Precision limit exceeded" error. Any value less then that (e.g. nTan(250)) will return as expected

Comment: OK. This error is thrown in a function `getLn10` when you exceed the length of the internally stored string for the natural logarithm of 10. in the repository, this is 1024 characters. Could it be, that you are using an older version of the lib, that stores a shorter string?

Comment: The error says it is from Decimal.js's tan function:
at ..., at nTan, at Decimal.P.tangent.P.tan, at Decimal.P.sine.P.sin, at toLessThanHalfPi, at getPi, at Error: [DecimalError] Precision limit exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1000000000** is the maximum permitted value for the [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js) **precision** setting, but that does not mean that the trigonometric methods can return a result to that number of significant digits.

The limit to the precision of the trigonometric methods is determined by the precision of the value of **Pi** in the source code. It is hard-coded in the *decimal.js* file as the string variable **`PI`**, and has a precision of **1025** digits.

This means that the precision limit for the **`cos`**, **`sin`** and **`tan`** methods is up to about **1000** digits, but the actual figure depends on the precision of the argument passed to them. To calculate the actual figure use

**maximum_result_precision = 1000 - argument_precision**

For example, the following both work fine

```
Decimal.set({precision: 991}).tan(123456789);

Decimal.set({precision: 9}).tan(991_digit_number);
```

as, for each, the result precision plus the argument precision, i.e. **`991 + 9`** and **`9 + 991`**, is less than or equal to **1000**.

This is why your program fails when you try and calculate the **`tan`** of an argument with more than **500** digits to a precision of more than **500** digits.

To do it would require **Pi** to a higher precision - and that can only be done, and can be done simply, by editing the value of **`PI`** in the source code, i.e. add more digits to it. The time taken by the methods will then be the limiting factor.

I am the library's author and I need to add this to its documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.